# Flask attribute error

Tags: python, flask

I can't import Flask 1.0 or run the development server all of a sudden.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_hackrun/iiec_hackrun.py", line 29, in <module>    start(fakepyfile,mainpyfile)                       File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/accomp_files/iiec_hackrun/iiec_hackrun.py", line 28, in start       exec(open(mainpyfile).read(),  __main__.__dict__)  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>                 File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>                               from .app import Flask, Request, Response          File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 25, in <module>                                    from . import cli, json                            File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/json/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>                          from itsdangerous import json as _json             File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/itsdangerous.py", line 38, in <module>                                 import simplejson as json
  File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    from .encoder import JSONEncoder, JSONEncoderForHTML
  File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 15, in <module>
    c_encode_basestring_ascii, c_make_encoder = _import_speedups()
  File "/data/data/ru.iiec.pydroid3/files/arm-linux-androideabi/lib/python3.6/site-packages/simplejson/encoder.py", line 12, in _import_speedups
    return _speedups.encode_basestring_ascii, _speedups.make_encoder
AttributeError: module 'markupsafe._speedups' has no attribute 'encode_basestring_ascii'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. At first I don't know where the error came from, I crossed check my codes thinking it came from their; not until I imported flask itself from the terminal.

Comment: Still the same, even uninstalling virtualenv itself.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use pipenv and try it again.

```
pip install pipenv

pipenv shell --three

pipenv install flask
```

Comment: If you use python2.7, you should use pipenv shell --two